# How to make a list of items individually toggleable with Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, toggle

Here's a [basic example](http://jsbin.com/nakibinazi/1/edit?html,output) of toggling a list of buttons, basically by doing `ng-click="selected = !selected"` in each of them. This means that by pressing one button, `selected` will be updated in all buttons at once, because it's set in the `$scope`.

There are two things I'd like to do: a) what would be an elegant way of toggling each individual button without updating all at once, and then b) keep those currently `selected` in an object in `$scope`? I want these buttons to act as real-time filters: hitting one of them should toggle it in a `$scope` object that contains only the `selected` filters.

Comment: You want a directive for each item with isolate scope.

Comment: If have list of items, then u use ng-repeat, then 'selected' will be different for all items. For real-time filters u need to store selected array and update it on ng-click.

Comment: @Dylan That seems like a good fit. If I apply a directive for each button, how would I access their individual scopes from the controller?

Comment: Ya, I suppose the simplest answer is that you need more variables.  Implementing that is done in several ways.  ex: http://jsbin.com/takucu/3/edit?html,js,output

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suggest setting up an ng-click function inside a controller to handle both of these at once. To toggle the buttons individually give each one its own unique variable within `selected` like I've done below. To add the button to an object of selected buttons you need to set up a controller with a function called with ng-click where you add or remove the button from the object.

```
<body ng-app>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <button data-active="{{ selected.a }}" ng-click="selected.a = !selected.a">Item 1 is {{ selected.a }}</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button data-active="{{ selected.b }}" ng-click="selected.b = !selected.b">Item 2 is {{ selected.b }}</button>
    </li>
    <li>
      <button data-active="{{ selected.c }}" ng-click="selected.c = !selected.c">Item 3 is {{ selected.c }}</button>
    </li>
  </ul>
</body>
```

Comment: Elegantly solved my two problems at once, and yet it barely touched my code. Hats off, @j_buckley.